# Remove UIView after animation without losing other elements

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

What happens if I toggle between these two for hundreds of times? will be left handers of unused `UIView`s?
I have several controls on my main `UIView` and I want to animate (slide-up and slide-down) them as a group of controls, several times, then I decided to add them to an `UIView` and animate that view. But It seems every time when I add the `view` to the `superView` it remains there and if I run `[view removeFromSuperView]` it also remove all controls I've added to the `view`. Does it affect performance or can it cause memory leak problem?

```
 (void)slideUp{
    repeatViewTop = datePickerButton.frame.origin.y;
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, repeatViewTop)];
    [view addSubview:taskTitle];
    [view addSubview:taskNote];
    [view addSubview:datePickerButton];
    [view addSubview:taskSelectedDateViewer];
    [self.view addSubview:view];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4f
                          delay:0.1f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^{
                         float tempY=view.frame.origin.y;
                         [view setCenter:CGPointMake(SCREEN_WIDTH/2,tempY)];
                         [view setAlpha:0.4f];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     }];
    [self.view insertSubview:view atIndex:0];
}
```

This will slide down those controls:

```
- (void)slideDown{
    taskTitle.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
    //150=view.frame.origin.y after sliding up
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -114, SCREEN_WIDTH, repeatViewTop)];
    [view addSubview:taskTitle];
    [view addSubview:taskNote];
    [view addSubview:datePickerButton];
    [view addSubview:taskSelectedDateViewer];
    [self.view addSubview:view];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4f
                          delay:0.1f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^{
                         float tempY=view.frame.origin.y *(-1);
                         [view setCenter:CGPointMake(SCREEN_WIDTH/2,tempY)];
                         [view setAlpha:1.0f];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){


                     }];
    [self.view insertSubview:view atIndex:0];
}
```

Comment: You should add the elements in a View only **once** and keep reference to your view, then animate it and not insert it all the time.

Comment: @Lefteris How to do it? I'm new to iOS programing

Comment: `@property (strong,nonatomic) UIView *viewA` and initialize it once and add as subview in `viewDidLoad` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the elements in a View only **once** and keep reference to your view, then animate it and not insert it all the time.

You can create the view at any time, like in the `viewDidLoad` delegate, like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    //Other code here


    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, repeatViewTop)];
    view.tag = 1999;
    [view addSubview:taskTitle];
    [view addSubview:taskNote];
    [view addSubview:datePickerButton];
    [view addSubview:taskSelectedDateViewer];
    [self.view addSubview:view];
}
```

then get a reference to the view in your animations like this:

```
(void)slideUp{
    repeatViewTop = datePickerButton.frame.origin.y;
    UIView *view = [self.view viewWithTag:1999];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4f
                          delay:0.1f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^{
                         float tempY=view.frame.origin.y;
                         [view setCenter:CGPointMake(SCREEN_WIDTH/2,tempY)];
                         [view setAlpha:0.4f];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     }];
}
```

Comment: I would only add as the first thing in `viewDidLoad` call `super` it won't change anything for now but it is a good practice to do this